# Password protected web content-- basic question

Tags: forms, password-protection

I'm looking to create a password-protected section of my website that requires user login, and I'm wondering what approach would provide the simplest solution. For the most part, the site will be very simple and static-- i.e. no real requirement for a database/backend-- with the protected content contained in a single directory, which I've already configured on my server via htaccess. I guess I'm wondering ultimately if it's possible to use a script of some sort that will enable access to this protected directory via a form and thereby bypass the need for configuring a mySQL/PHP solution? Furthermore, this protected content is not exactly hyper-sensitive, but private nonetheless.

Thanks much for any direction here.

Comment: When you say you've "configured on my server via htaccess", do you mean that you've already set up basic password authentication in htaccess? Or are you asking how to do that?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry if I wasn't clear-- I've already protected a directory on my server in htaccess; now I'm wondering if there's some way to basically create an html login form that will enable access to the directory content-- I realize users will get a login dialog upon attempting to access "domain.com/protected-dir/index.html" for example, but I'd rather that they're presented with a web page to prompt for credentials

Comment: Stick with the prompt from the server; it's easiest and does what you want. It's also reasonably standard.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I would set up an ordinary (public) HTML page that is the "entry" page to your protected content. It would describe what it is and how to log in (or whatever), and provide an ordinary link to log in. That link would go to the directory you've password protected, which would bring up a browser popup box requesting username and password.

This scheme is about 99% of the functionality of a login form, with about 1% of the hassle.

Comment: thanks for the responses guys; curious though what the simplest alternative would be, i.e. to be able to create that custom login page? it's not an absolute requirement, I just envisioned the design of a drop down ajax-style login prompt... I would imagine this would entail setting up a database with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could write some PHP script for delegating the web server to forward files after your customised authentication.

You may need to install `mod_xsendfile` for Apache and use `X-Sendfile`.
For Nginx, just use `X-Accel-Redirect`.

I think it is not common, but for some reasons, it can be useful.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/
https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

---

It's too old question! I didn't noticed the date since I'm still new to this site. Sorry for bothering.